# Phillips (non-dimmable) 60W LED bulbs breaking in the light fixture

Tags: electrical, led

I replaced all of my light bulbs (CFL's) with Phillips 60W LEDs when they were on sale with coupons last October 2017.  They claim they will last 13+ years if used  4hours / day for 7 days a week.  6 months later.... they are flickering in the lights (overhead ceiling fixtures/no dimmers).  When I take a look, the bulb has separated where the metal socket and glass bulb meet -hanging off the insides of the bulb and the interior white coating is missing in spots.
Home Depot has given me my money back for some... but they cannot explain what is happening to them.  Phillips is asking for receipts - which I do not have anymore.  I am about to ramp up my discussion with Phillips - but wondered if anyone else has had similar issues?

Comment: What sort of fixtures are you using these bulbs in? Are they fully enclosed? Which way do the bulbs face, and is there any ventilation?

Comment: Home Depot can regenerate the receipt using the card you paid with.

Comment: I have had LED lamps fail within 1 year, in every case that I have disassembled the lamp the driver failed (all LED's iluminated with power supply) or the lamp failed because overheating (some have tiny fans to cool them) when the fan fails the lamp overheats and fails.

Comment: Do the bulbs have a wide base? Do the fixtures have a flange which sticks up above the socket which the wide base might possibly bind against, keeping it from bottoming out in the socket?

Comment: I trust these are *60W equivalent* and actually around 9-12W. If 60W actual, that'll be over 50W of heat...

Answer (score 1):

Many LED lamps are designed to ONLY be used **base down** because the LED "driver" (the power supply board that is the equivalent of the ballast in a CFL lamp) must be able to dissipate the heat. It likely said so in small font on the packaging, but you didn't notice or didn't realize what that means. In some cases the mfr is less than forthright about that though, and a quick look at Phillips' site makes me think they are in that category. When used in things like overhead fans where the base is up AND the air cannot flow around it, the heat of the driver cannot escape to the surrounding air and the glue holding it all together separates.

Read this; very informative. https://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/readers--choice-2013--toyota-s-killer-firmware--epic-apple-fails--raspberry-pi--more/4423570/That-60W-equivalent-LED--What-you-don-t-know--and-what-no-one-will-tell-you-

Answer (score 0):

Over heating most likely. The ballasts in the compact fluorescents need free air all around them. I had a ceiling fan with 4 lights. The glass for the light shades was almost touching the ballasts. I would write the date on the bulbs with a Sharpie. They would last almost exactly 1 year. The fact that I kept the fan running continually probably made them last a little longer.

Comment: The OP has LED bulbs, not CFLs.

Comment: Oops, my bad. But thinking about it, may still be the same problem.